# OpenAM error 500 "Unable to do Single Sign On or Federation" when browser loads successURL

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, openam

I just installed OpenAM 13.0.0, created an hosted IDP, and registered a remote SP.
Within the remote SP (a product called Questetra), I configured the entityID, login URL, logout URL, and certificate using values found in the XML at http://idp:8080/openam/saml2/jsp/exportmetadata.jsp?entityid=http://idp:8080/openam&realm=/

Problem: OpenAM says `500 Internal Server Error` at the step where the browser loads the `successURL`.

- Any idea what is happening?
- Any tips on how to debug? There is nothing special in the Tomcat and OpenAM logs.

## Shortened Wireshark trace

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[...]

{"successURL":"/SSORedirect/metaAlias/idp?ReqID=a41de50e29c99ff3422f82b7g660ch6&index=null&acsURL=http%3A%2F%2Fthesp%3A8080%2Fuserweb%2Fsaml%2FSSO%2Falias%2Fbpm&spEntityID=http%3A%2F%2Fthesp%3A8080%2Fuserweb%2F&binding=urn%3Aoasis%3Anames%3Atc%3ASAML%3A2.0%3Abindings%3AHTTP-POST"}

GET /openam/SSORedirect/metaAlias/idp?ReqID=a41de50e29c99ff3422f82b7g660ch6&index=null&acsURL=http%3A%2F%2Fthesp%3A8080%2Fuserweb%2Fsaml%2FSSO%2Falias%2Fbpm&spEntityID=http%3A%2F%2Fthesp%3A8080%2Fuserweb%2F&binding=urn%3Aoasis%3Anames%3Atc%3ASAML%3A2.0%3Abindings%3AHTTP-POST HTTP/1.1
[...]

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
[...]

<html>[...]HTTP Status 500 - Unable to do Single Sign On or Federation[...]</html>
```

Full trace at https://gist.github.com/nicolas-raoul/5ff26f37a95bc8088c6af7fe6ea5e468

Tomcat 7.0.72, Ubuntu 2016.04.1 LTS, Firefox 50.1.0

Comment: Set OpenAM debug logging to 'message' level and check Federation debug log (or provide the error here)

Comment: Hey Nicolas, were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this same error by taking the Certificate value directly from the metadata file exported from OpenAM and entering that directly again, to ensure that it was the exact same.